# AP22802 Load Switch Sometimes Burning Unexpectedly!

Tags: switching-transients

### [image][image: Picture of AP22802 Loadswitch Sot23-5/Sot25 Package]

I have been using AP22802 high-side load switch on many projects for non-inductive loads without any problem until now.
But sometimes it was burning even it has light loads (5V/10~150mA). 
If input capacitance is lower than output/load capacitance it burns because of unkown effect. 
but it works any problem most of times.

Any idea about why it is burning sometimes even on light loads?

The list of people who have similar issues with AP22802: 
https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/newaetech/phywhispererusb/5/578445400
https://forums.parallax.com/discussion/comment/1479361
https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/weird-load-switch-problem-ap22802-with-bluetooth-hc-05-module/
[http://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management/f/196/p/744690/2780431#2780431?jktype=e2e]
[6]

[6]: http://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management/f/196/p/744690/2780431#2780431?jktype=e2e## Heading ##

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that reverse current/voltage is causing this failure and IC is burning because of delay on turnoff period while switching off.

I stopped using AP22802 on my projects and now using AP22814 / AP22811 which has Reverse Current/Voltage blocking and Soft-Start features.

[image: TurnOn-TurnOff Delay and Rise/Fall Time Charts]
[image: Loadswitch Features - Overall]
[image: Reverse Current/Voltage Protection Charts]

Comment: I think "Load switch" Tag should be added to electronics.stackexchange section